# phong equation of illumination specular component

Tags: raytracing, specular

I'm stuck on this question asking me to calculate the intensity of a pixel using Ray Tracing. It gives values such as $I_i$ but doesn't give any coordinates.

I know for the diffuse component, $I_ik_d(n,l)$ can be written as $I_ik_d(\cos\theta)$ but for the specular component $I_ik_s(h\cdot n)$ is there any other way to write it so that it doesn't require any vectors such as $h$ and $n$?

This is the question:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want N·H, or do you want R·L i.e. reflection vector dotted with light source vector? The latter would be the classic Phong equation (N·H is Blinn), and the figure appears to mark the R·L angle: 15 degrees.

Comment: Should the question not point out which Bidirectional Reflectance Distribution Function (BRDF) you need to use? You have Phong, Blinn-Phong, Modified Phong, Modified Blinn-Phong and a whole variety of physically-based ones.

Comment: @NathanReed how can i find R.L if i dont know the vectors? Do i just use 15 degrees?

Comment: @user2976568 The dot product is the cosine of the angle between the vectors (for unit vectors). Just as you remarked that N·L = cos(theta). :)

Comment: @NathanReed sounds like the answer to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the classic Phong model is desired here, the dot product that goes into the specular calculation should be R·L, rather than N·H (which was introduced by Blinn). That is, Phong calculates specular using the angle between the reflected eye vector and the light vector.

In the diagram you posted, these vectors are shown and the angle is given as 15°. So, R·L = cos(15°) = 0.96 according to the table below the diagram.